# Git fetch/pull/clone hangs on receiving objects

Tags: git, ssh, scp

When fetching or pulling from git repositories, or cloning a repository, I get to this point:

```
remote: Counting objects: 6666, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5941/5941), done.
Receiving objects:  23% (1534/6460), 11.68 MiB | 23 KiB/s
```

And it hangs. The 23%/number of objects isn't a given, it ranges from single digits to up to the 60s, it seems. Also the speed for download listed freezes -- it's not like it slowly crawls down towards zero.

The guy I sit next to has no issues, so it's not a router problem. We use beanstalk for our work repositories, but I have the issue from beanstalk and github (although occaisonally it seems a github one will finish).

The problem has only seemed to crop up since upgrading to Mountain Lion and updating Xcode. I've wiped git (including XCode's) and tried installing it with homebrew. That didn't work, so I removed it and tried with their provided Mac installation package which also didn't fix the issue.

Beanstalk provides SSH urls for the git repository, but I've had no issues with connecting via SCP or SSH to servers that I've done work on.

This is killing my workflow so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You try a new repository clone when you wiped git or has this been the same local repo each time?

Comment: Forgot to say that -- it's both with fetch on already existing ones and trying to clone new repos

Comment: Does the same error apply to every git repository, or just this particular codebase? For example, if you clone [git's source,](https://github.com/git/git) does it exhibit similar symptoms?

Comment: Is this because of another app? (an anti-virus for instance, like in http://openforum.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Anti-Virus-for-Mac-Home/Sophos-Causing-Mountain-Lion-to-Hang-Spinning-beach-balls-and/td-p/8195), or do you have one component which is known to hang in its current version with Mountain Lion (see http://roaringapps.com/search:site/q/hang)

Comment: I did have Sophos, which I removed. I've gone through and cleaned out everything, so there's no other applications open, and I cleared out as many background processes as I could. Same issue occurs.

Comment: Any solution you found? I am facing exact same problem while cloning mediawiki sources.

Comment: I ended up wiping my system and going back to Lion. Only other thing I'd suggest trying is cloning with "--depth 1"

Answer (score 25):

VMware on *NAT* had this problem for me. Changing it to *Bridged (replicate the state)* fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I lost so many hours trying to work around a Github servers limitation, when the solution was in reality so easy... My problem happened when cloning the CocoaPods specs repo, so I figured it was related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever ... It was not, just a network issue.

Answer (score 13):

Looks similar to mine problem. Git seemed to hang on fetch or push after a certain short amount of time.
I can advice you to put in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *

ServerAliveInterval 60
```

I have a MBP with also mountain lion. I hope this timeout is the cause for your problem.
(After thirty or forty minutes or so, I noticed that it continued.)

Answer (score 10):

Try to check your network connection. Maybe there is a garbage in the routing table. Maybe broken port on your router or your computer's network interface problem. Try to ping server from which you are cloning git repo, maybe link between your computer and this server is unstable.

Comment: I had the same issue and your suggestion worked. I pinged github.com -t and clone started receiving the objects.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. The clone for any repo on github is still stuck at a certain percentage...

Comment: For some reason, your MTU might be set too high. Try lowering the MTU in one of the machines, temporarily, to determine if the cause relates to that.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, git fetch should be more resistant to this kind of issue, with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019): On platforms where "git fetch" is killed with SIGPIPE (e.g. OSX), the `upload-pack` that runs on the other end that hangs up after detecting an error could cause "`git fetch`" to die with a signal, which led to a flakey test.
"`git fetch`" now ignores SIGPIPE during the network portion of its operation (this is not a problem as we check the return status from our write(2)s).

See [commit 1435889](https://github.com/git/git/commit/143588949c8a0672302403c722fc433a5bb2ea2a) (03 Mar 2019), and [commit 37c8001](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37c80012f1415bc4ff23def735a87cbd395bca31) (05 Mar 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 27cdbdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27cdbdd134f181fc97f9589039ed7c0d12759b5a), 20 Mar 2019)</sup>

> ### `fetch`: ignore `SIGPIPE` during network operation
>
> The default `SIGPIPE` behavior can be useful for a command that generates
>   a lot of output: if the receiver of our output goes away, we'll be
>   notified asynchronously to stop generating it (typically by killing the
>   program).
>
> But for a command like `fetch`, which is primarily concerned with
>   receiving data and writing it to disk, an unexpected `SIGPIPE` can be
>   awkward. We're already checking the return value of all of our `write()`
>   calls, and dying due to the signal takes away our chance to gracefully
>   handle the error.
>
> On Linux, we wouldn't generally see `SIGPIPE` at all during fetch. If the
>   other side of the network connection hangs up, we'll see `ECONNRESET`.
>   But on OS X, we get a `SIGPIPE`, and the process is killed.
>
> Let's ignore `SIGPIPE` during the network portion of the fetch, which will
>   cause our `write()` to return `EPIPE`, giving us consistent behavior across
>   platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the git credentials worked for me.

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks

Answer (score -28):

first try to initialize git repository folder by typing

```
$ git init
```

it should help

Comment: `git clone` automatically calls `git init`.