# git clone ends with Broken Pipe

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

I have a very big git repository and want to clone from it. On **one machine (ArchLinux with git version 2.2.2)** everything works fine...

```
Cloning into 'foo'
remote: Counting objects: 2372505, done
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (456914/456914), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (2372505/2372505), 3.81 GiB | 6.20 MiB/s, done.
...
```

... but **on another machine (Ubuntu with git version 2.3.0, also tried with 1.7.0.4)**, I only see the following:

```
Cloning into 'foo'
remote: Counting objects: 2372505, done.
```

and after some hours, it ends with

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

**Any idea what's the problem?**

By the way:

- The remote end is a gitlab server.
- I'm using SSH in both cases.
- The first (working) machine is connected via VPN (100 MBit/s).
- The second (non-working) machine is in the same gigabit-subnet as the gitlab server.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Because, the firewall sometimes breaks the communication that results in this. I do not know how and why.
BTW, which version of git are you using?

Comment: No. As already mentioned: The client is in the same subnet as the server. I also thought it could be a problem with the old git version (1.7.0.4) but after an upgrade to 2.3.0 the problem is still there.

Comment: Does this help? http://hungred.com/how-to/gitlab-error-fatal-remote-hung-unexpectedly/

Comment: This is another problem. I also had this when I installed gitlab one year ago but I already fixed it back then.

Comment: In my case, I had to turn off my WiFi and turn it back on again. Rest of internet was working, including fast.com, but for some reason no GitHub operations were working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved!** I used a DNS name for connecting to the gitlab server, and what I didn't know: This name has been resolved to the external IP of the same server, so, **the server and the client were not in the same subnet**.

So, the client connected to the external IP of the server, so the firewall had to NAT it back to the server.

**The solution** was quite simple: I just added the hostname with the internal ip to the client machine's `/etc/hosts` file and from that on the clone worked like a charm.

Comment: Great catch, more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: Yeah. Was my mistake because the question was faulty. But thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem: hopefully, it will help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding GitLab, [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gitlabhq/index-pack$20failed/gitlabhq/ZkK1eGve0gQ/3KBKdg_gwmkJ) mentions (for a similar error)

> I solved that issue (unable to checkout large repo' via HTTP) by editing [`git/config/unicorn.yml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/unicorn.rb.example) and setting timeout to 120, when it was previously 30, and restarting the gitab service.

If this is not only about the Git hosting server, but about Git itself, then you have other options to try:

- [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141471/6309)
- [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317479/6309)

Comment: I'm not using HTTP for checkout. Furthermore, I don't think it's caused by gitlab, since I am able to clone the repo with other machines.

Comment: @EthanLeroy how about some local Git config then (https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398650-git-clone-GitURL-may-fail-with-error-fatal-index-pack-failed): `git config pack.windowMemory 10m && git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m `

Comment: @EthanLeroy another approach, just for testing: `git in it && git remote add origin <ssh/url/of/gitlab/repo> && git pull origin master`

Comment: with `remote add`: Good idea, but same problem.

Comment: with `config pack...`: Wow! Now it also does `Compressing objects` and starts `Receiving objects`, but there it got stuck at 3%. What does it mean?

Comment: @EthanLeroy maybe the ssh connection isn't resilient enough for this operation? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17494901/6309)

Comment: I set `ServerAliveInterval` to 60, but makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

For me, after trying out all suggestions found on the net, it turned out that the VPN connection was connecting and disconnecting constantly. It seems that if there is too many "network outages" or a lossy network, git clone "jams" and eventually you get the Broken pipe-error message.

To debug, if there is any real traffic going on, you can use

```
iptraf
```

or

```
tcpdump -ni eth0 host github.com
```

In my case, there was initially a steady flow of 2MB/s, but after a few secs, the underlying connection broke down, and the clone stream never recovered, until I fixed the OpenVPN connection to stay up more stable.