# cloning github through SSH auth with multiple accounts freezes

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I've created and set up multiple ssh keys for authenticating with multiple github accounts. After successfully tried it out by means of `ssh -T`command, I tried to clone a repo, but this freezes unexpectedly:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo:.ssh matteo$ ssh -T git@github.com-bertamini.matteo
Hi bertuz-gist! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo:.ssh matteo$ git clone git@github.com-bertamini.matteo:bertuz/bertuzFox.git tst
Cloning into 'tst'...
remote: Counting objects: 253, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
```

I can't figure out if it is my fault or a temporary github glitch. Any help?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/17494901/6309 help?

Comment: I would have helped, but I figured out that the wifi I was using used to block git connections. Now everything works smoothly. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: no need to delete: it can help others. I have added an answer to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by "[Git fetch/pull/clone hangs on receiving objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11941175/6309)", that kind of issue is generally caused by:

- the remote side having an issue (but GitHub status history doesn't show any issue)
- the network (middle or client side)
- the ssh config, if ssh url are used (`ServerAliveInterval 60`)

The [OP Bertuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192829/bertuz) confirms in the comments the reason is the second one (network):

> The wifi I was using used to block git connections.
>   Now everything works smoothly. Shall I delete the question?