# git fetch origin just stops doesn't do anything

Tags: git, repository, git-fetch

I have git branches on a remote server They are like:

```
origin/ABCD
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/XYZP
origin/PQRS
```

I see them when I run `git branch -r`.

Now, I am at a local machine, which is connected to the remote server, and I am on a local branch say ABCD.

```
* ABCD
```

I wish to update the remote branch for my local machine, so that I can see the code. I do:

```
git fetch origin
```

but nothing happens; it just stops, even though it used to ask for the remote server's password. What's happening?

Comment: Do you get your prompt back after running `git fetch origin`, or does the process keep running?

Comment: it just stops nothing happens, nothing prints, I have to press ctrl+c to get the prompt back.

Comment: See if the suggestions [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941175/git-fetch-pull-clone-hangs-on-receiving-objects) help.