# Git clone hangs in Windows bash

Tags: git, clone, freeze

When I run the command `git clone -v [repo]` it gets to

> Receiving objects: 24%

and just hangs forever.  I have canceled and re-tried about 1/2 dozen times and every time it gets to a different percentage and hangs. I have disabled my AVG firewall to no avail.
Using Windows Server 2012
Git bash version 1.9.4

Comment: Can you attempt an `init`, `remote add`, and then a `fetch` to see if the fetch is the issue?

Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941175/git-fetch-pull-clone-hangs-on-receiving-objects

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just taking a while because there is a really large blob in the history somewhere? git only updates the percentage once it completes a whole file.

Answer (score 7):

Try these option for more debugging ...

```
GIT_TRACE=1; GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --verbose http://github.com/rajasimon/yourproject.git
```

Comment: Whats the equivalent in windows ?

Comment: The `--verbose` flag allowed **Git Credential Manager** window to pop up so I could authorize my computer to clone a repository. Thanks!