# Git clone hangs on Receiving objects on MAC OSX 10.12

Tags: ios, git, macos, terminal, cocoapods

I am trying to setup Cocoapods on mac osx 10.12, I have tried to execute this command in terminal it hangs on receiving object :-

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
GIT_TRACE=1; GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone http://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --verbose
```

Here is the terminal output:-

```
            Cloning into 'master'...
            * Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
            *   Trying 192.30.253.112...
            * Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 80 (#0)
            > GET /CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
            Host: github.com
            User-Agent: git/2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
            Accept: */*
            Accept-Encoding: gzip
            Pragma: no-cache

            < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
            < Content-length: 0
            < Location: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
            < Connection: close
            < 
            * Closing connection 0
            * Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
            * Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
            *   Trying 192.30.253.112...
            * Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#1)
            * TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
            * Server certificate: github.com
            * Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
            * Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
            > GET /CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
            Host: github.com
            User-Agent: git/2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
            Accept: */*
            Accept-Encoding: gzip
            Pragma: no-cache

            < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
            < Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
            < Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
            < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
            < Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
            < Pragma: no-cache
            < Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
            < Vary: Accept-Encoding
            < X-GitHub-Request-Id: 69EEB048:2D36F:6AF964:57888CD0
            < X-Frame-Options: DENY
            < 
            * Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
            POST git-upload-pack (305 bytes)
            * Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
            * Found bundle for host github.com: 0x7fc3d750be30
            * Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host github.com
            * Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#1)
            > POST /CocoaPods/Specs.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
            Host: github.com
            User-Agent: git/2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
            Accept-Encoding: gzip
            Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
            Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
            Content-Length: 305

            * upload completely sent off: 305 out of 305 bytes
            < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
            < Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
            < Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
            < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
            < Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
            < Pragma: no-cache
            < Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
            < Vary: Accept-Encoding
            < X-GitHub-Request-Id: 69EEB048:2D36F:6AFF66:57888CD9
            < X-Frame-Options: DENY
            < 
            remote: Counting objects: 747987, done.
            remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
            Receiving objects:   1% (10862/747987), 2.16 MiB | 437.00 KiB/s
```

I have seen others questions about this issue here on SO, unfortunately non of there solutions worked.

**Update:-**

The terminal showed this error after a while:-

```
* SSLRead() return error -9806/747987), 2.16 MiB | 437.00 KiB/s   
* Closing connection 1
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm it's a network issue on my side. I executed this command on a Windows 10 machine:-

`git clone http://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

Then copied the master repo to this directory on the MAC OSX machine using the terminal cp command (normal copy using Finder hangs for hours):-

`~/.cocoapods/repos/master`

Then finally doing pod init then pod install --verbose on my project directory worked like a charm

Answer (score 8):

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41738019/601170)

> VMware on NAT had this problem for me. Changing it to Bridged
>   (replicate the state) fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: if someone has troubles with `Bridged`, try reset `vmware network settings` - `Vmware / Edit / Virtual Network Editor` , press `Restore Defaults`, also select the right adapter for `VMnet0` (in my case it's Realtek) - https://s13.postimg.org/hrh9ctmfr/Screenshot_3.png