# Git stuck while receiving objects

Tags: git, github

A look of projects while downloading looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/anyproject/project.git /var/folders/nc/fk4zxcg13w99jjkjfcv_1p3h0000gn/T/d20160909-5467-gcadxt --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.7.0 --verbose
Cloning into '/var/folders/nc/fk4zxcg13w99jjkjfcv_1p3h0000gn/T/d20160909-5467-gcadxt'...
POST git-upload-pack (155 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (164 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 220, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (191/191), done.
Receiving objects:  52% (115/220), 8.94 MiB | 1.79 MiB/s   s
```

Why does Git hang? It can continue eventually! I'm using MacOS.

Comment: git version? firewall? anti virus software? try cloing via ssh, consider updating git.

Comment: In my experience the progress is by object count and is kind of suspended when a large object is being transferred.

Comment: What do you mean by "It can continue eventually"? Does it just hang for a while and then continue?

Comment: It hangs. Anyway i found the solution. Problem was about network connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41738019/601170)

> VMware on NAT had this problem for me. Changing it to Bridged (replicate the state) fixed the issue.

Comment: After an hour of googling, this was the answer. Anyone have any idea why sharing the hosts IP (NAT mode) would cause git to bork?