# git clone project with large file freeze

Tags: git, gitlab

I git clone a project from gitlab server, the project has a large file about 90Mb,
git command will be freeze, i have tried serveral times but get the same result.  The freeze state as follow:

```
Cloning into 'GPU-HOOK'...
remote: Counting objects: 29, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Receiving objects:  24% (7/29), 41.99 MiB | 430.00 KiB/s
```

how to deal with it?

Comment: Does it ever recover? By "freeze" do you mean "keeps hanging forever" or simply "takes a very long time"? If the latter, how long is long?

Comment: Nerver recovery

Comment: Try `SET GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and `SET GIT_TRACE=1`, and then rerun the git command, this will output a lot of debug information, see if you spot anything there that might explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your [GitLab server configuration file (`gitlab.yml`)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8265fe3954e225d58567878fd9200acbe84ad296/config/gitlab.yml.example#L508-518) the value of `max_size`:

```
  ## Git settings
  # CAUTION!
  # Use the default values unless you really know what you are doing
  git:
    bin_path: /usr/bin/git
    # The next value is the maximum memory size grit can use
    # Given in number of bytes per git object (e.g. a commit)
    # This value can be increased if you have very large commits
    max_size: 20971520 # 20.megabytes
    # Git timeout to read a commit, in seconds
    timeout: 10
```

You also can have a similar setting in your web server frontend (NGiNX for instance)

But if you are using an ssh url, that would not matter. [Check instead your own local ssh config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494901/6309).