# not able to clone repos from gitlab as the commanf git clone has been stuck

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I ran the following command to clone the git:

```
git clone git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx:xxxxxxx/xxxx/anxxxx-xxx.git

Cloning into 'xxx-xxxx'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 80, done.
remote: Counting objects:  31% (25/80)
```

This is simply stuck in this stage indefinitely. I'm using ubuntu 16 as WSL.

It was worked before but today I deleted the local repo from my machine and tried to clone it again but got hang. Do you have any idea or questions please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try and clone a *small* repository, to see if the issue persists.

It could be a `~/.ssh/config` setting issue [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494901/6309).

For a large repository, a [shallow cone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) first (meaning without the full history) might help.